# Magento 2 Theme Customization

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, customization, magento2

1 how to change theme name to custom name in magento 2? 
2 After changing what steps i should  need to do ?
3 Important changing name in front end as same as backed ?

Thank you in advance .

Comment: See the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a theme, assign parent theme (I suggest Magento/luma to get all css) http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
2. Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.
3. If there are errors in the 2 step check your theme declaration
4. Not quite understood what you want, but if you follow 1 and 2 step, your theme should appear in the admin->design->themes list (after setup:upgrade)

p.s. And yes, you should read official documentation